# Unable to ping my remote local host using Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: json, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Hi everyone I am working on Hyperledger Fabric . While working on balance-transfer directory I am facing certain error while running the script ./runApp.sh .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Mxc.png)

I have tried to ping my local host using POST to get my username : Jim and Organisation ID:Org1 it shows success

> failed  and the username is invalid .

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are running on Windows and unfortunately on Windows you can't access Docker containers via "localhost".
When you start Docker via the QuickStart Terminal, it will print out an endpoint address.  You'll want to copy that address and then in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/app/network-config.json you'll want to replace references to "localhost" with that IP address